# Bevel isn't working on the "walls" that I just modeled

Tags: bevel

Bevel isn't working on the "walls" that I just modeled. I can add it but there seems to be no effect, even if I cranked up the settings. Still learning Blender.

[My blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fm_QqbZkQfhDGh3uYZGnJd_GLcnbY7b0) .

or try this link
[image]

Comment: there can be several reasons, please at least show a screenshot of your wireframe

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=E3oywlVz" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/E3oywlVz/)

Comment: what part are you trying to bevel? What we can see is that you have vertices overlapping, so first thing, use alt M to merge by distance, then try again

Comment: @moonboots the whole thing? I'm only following this guy's tutorial and he clicked the entire model and added bevel on all of it. here's a link 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8XSQhRcpfM&t=4s

exactly on the 20:00 minute mark is where he added the bevel

Comment: oh ok it's a bevel modifier, but same thing, you need to alt M > Merge by distance in order to get rid of overlapping vertices, and in the Operator box (bottom left of the 3D view) put the factor at 0.001, you'll see that it will delete a lot of vertices (bottom right of the blender interface), now bevel will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* in order to get rid of overlapping vertices. In the *Operator* box (bottom left of the 3D view) put the factor at 0.001, you'll see that it will delete a lot of vertices (bottom right of the blender interface). Now bevel operation or *Bevel* modifier will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your walls are planes and cannot be beveled with a modifier. You need to give your object a "solidify modifier" first and a "bevel modifier" second. Next in "bevel modifier" under "Geometry" turn off "Clamp Overlap". This will show where you need to clean up your mesh.